# Magnolia Upgrade from maven

Tags: maven, upgrade, magnolia

I have Magnolia 5.4.9 release and I want to upgrade it to 5.4.18 from maven pom file. The problem is that in nexus repository there are pom files til the release 5.4.10. If I try to reach 5.4.11 or later, then I get this error:

[image: 404 error][1]

Is there any solution to upgrade 5.4.11 and later?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'Maintenance releases for previous major versions of Magnolia are available to Magnolia On-Premises customers only (i.e. customers that have an active subscription to Magnolia On-Premises).' https://www.magnolia-cms.com/support/maintenance-policy.html, Unfortunate enough that's the policy.

In this case I see two alternatives:

Sending an email to info@magnolia-cms.com
or you want to upgrade to later release anyway, just giving it a shot in test env. or similar.

Should you an enterprise user: please login to Magnolia Nexus and get the version you wish. If your maven settings are accurate, you should have no problem fetching those dependencies as well. https://wiki.magnolia-cms.com/display/DEV/Maven+setup

Cheers,